# Multiple ASP.NET pages on one page

Tags: asp.net

I would like to have multiple pages display on one page using asp.net. The intention is that those pages show their updates (I have a timer control that updates the pages), but I as a user should not be able to interact with them. When I click on one of those pages, it will then take me to that page and I as a user will then be able to interact with that page.

How is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do the first part with a pair of iframes that load the two ASP pages you want.

For the second part, I know there's an image hosting service (can't remember which one) that puts a a single clear pixel image overtop of the image you're looking at.  It's stretched across the entire image so that when you right-click and save, you're saving that single clear pixel and not the image you're looking at.  It's a lame form of security that may have an application here.

Barring that, you could have the iframes point to a "dummied" version of the ASP pages that don't have any of the interactivity, and a link above each iframe to take you to the real version.  Perhaps you could write a filter that removes all the interactivity from any page to avoid update anomalies (aka you update the real page, then you gotta update the dummied page).

With that, I'm at the end of what I can say with confidence.  Perhaps another iframe overtop (can you do that?) of each of the ASP page iframes that is a link to the actual page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I figured out the answer:

.one
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            zoom: 55%;
        }
        .opacitycss1
        {
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 600px;
            height: 350px;
            background-color: Black;
        }
        .opacitycss2
        {
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            position: absolute;
            left: 610px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 600px;
            height: 350px;
            background-color: Black;
        }
        .opacitycss3
        {
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 360px;
            width: 600px;
            height: 350px;
            background-color: Black;
        }
        .opacitycss4
        {
            filter: alpha(opacity=0);
            position: absolute;
            left: 610px;
            top: 360px;
            width: 600px;
            height: 350px;
            background-color: Black;
        }

Comment: You should still accept an answer so that the question won't be listed as Unanswered.